# Toggling flex wrap and nowrap on and off based on flex-item height

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have an issue with wrapping and no wrapping on my flexbox for a responsive design. I have two flex items side by side horizontally. The first item has a width of 340px and will never change. The second item next door is dynamic text. I use flex-grow to make it grow to the end of the flex container. However, this does not wrap when the viewbox shrinks for responsive design.

How do I toggle flex-wrap and nowrap on and off based on the max-height of the second item? So if the content of the second item goes past max-height of 300px, I want to go from no-wrap to wrap.

This is so my whitespace is mitigated between the desktop version of my app and the mobile version.

Comment: your dynamic text is known or it can change at any time? if it's known you can approximate what you want with flex-basis

Comment: It is dynamic. I might try to play with flex-basis a bit though.

Comment: I cannot find any good way to do this. I need to wrap after the 2nd item hits a max-height of 300px and then it should go to the next line.

Comment: there is no CSS solution for what you want, you will need JS and test the height on screen resize

Comment: the flex-basis is working with an absolute with of x pixels

Comment: please post a demo with all relevant code

Comment: Try using media queries